# Visual Studio Community 2017 cl linker won't link GTK3 libraries?

Tags: c, linker, gtk3, cl

I am writing code in C using GTK as GUI toolbox. I installed GTK3 via MSYS2 and managed to compile and build using GCC (TDM-Dragon) alright.

However, lately I am trying to compile and link using cl included in Visual Studio Community 2017 (heard it is faster and more stable). With this, I am having a hard time building an application. I am loosely following this tutorial:
http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/22

I created a BAT file and invoke it from the VS 2017 command prompt:

```
set GINC_PATH="C:\msys64\mingw64\include"
set GLIB_PATH="C:\msys64\mingw64\lib"
cl gtk3test.c -I"%GINC_PATH%\gtk-3.0" -I"%GINC_PATH%\glib-2.0" -I"%GLIB_PATH%\glib-2.0\include" -I"%GINC_PATH%\pango-1.0" -I"%GINC_PATH%\cairo" -I"%GINC_PATH%\gdk-pixbuf-2.0" -I"%GINC_PATH%\atk-1.0" -Dinline= /link /LIBPATH:%GLIB_PATH% gtk-3.lib gdk-3.lib gobject-2.0.lib glib-2.0.lib
```

This compiles alright, gives me gtk3test.obj. However, the linker returns the following error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'gtk-3.lib'

What am I doing wrong here? How would it be possible to use cl for linking GTK3 applications?

Thank you all in advance!

Xuttuh

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have `gtk-3.lib` in your folder path `[%GINC_PATH%]`. Even I have this issue using *GTK+3.0*, the package configuration is not giving the proper library reference.

The gtk library is something like `gtk-win32-3.0.lib` available inside `lib` folder `%GINC_PATH%\lib` in your case.

I still have issues in linking GTK libraries in my visual studio application even after providing the needed library references in Linker.